# Which is better for building API that access Cosmos DB using Azure Function, using Binding or SDK?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to create a backend API using Azure Function that reads & writes to a Cosmos DB database. After some reading, I found these two documentations:
[Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-add-output-binding-cosmos-db-vs-code?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-javascript#configure-your-environment)
[SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-api-sdk-node)
For my purpose, I think both of these methods can work just fine. The question is, which is better in general? And, what edge does one have over the other?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the APIs that you are building, a simple answer would be to use the binding if it works for your scenario that means you can directly bind parameters of the request to the Cosmos DB to read/insert.

In general, the bindings are basically to save your time from the burden of coding against SDKs directly, one example would be Bindings simplify the connection invocation, you don’t need to code specific connection logic.